# Passing JavaScript arrays to functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

A general question on JavaScript. If I have a function which modifies an array, such as:

```
var some_array = [];

function a_function(input, array){

    //do stuff to array
    return array;

}
```

In most languages:

```
var some_array = [];

some_array = a_function(input, some_array);

console.log(some_array);
```

works, however in js the below works as well:

```
var some_array = [];

a_function(input, some_array);

console.log(some_array);
```

Is this correct and how is this working?

Comment: Arrays are objects. Objects are passed by reference. `some_array` and `array` are the exact same in-memory array.

Comment: What error? This is a completely valid syntax in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks - passed by reference is exactly what I needed to know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in JS are objects and are passed into functions by value, where that value is a reference to the array. In other words, an array passed as an argument to a function still points to the same memory as the outer array.

This means that changing the array contents within the function changes the array passed from outside the function.

```js
function f(arr) {
  arr.push(1); 
  return arr;
}

var array = [];

// both function calls bellow add an element to the same array and then return a reference to that array. 

// adds an element to the array and returns it.
// It overrides the previous reference to the array with a 
// new reference to the same array.
array = f(array);
console.log(array); // [1]

// adds an element to the array and ignores the returned reference.
f(array);
console.log(array); // [1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a problem with circular objects, however I think I found the error there. I am removing that part from my question to keep things clear.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I updated my answer to correspond to your edited question